# Translate Russian "ненаглядный" to English

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, russian

How can you translate the Russian word "ненаглядный" preserving its meaning and semantics?
It is usually translated as dear or beloved but these words does not have the original meaning of the Russian word.

It can be translated as "the one who cannot be looked enough at".
But this phrase is too long and complicated to use e.g. as term of endearment.

Comment: How about "adored"?

Comment: I believe the corresponding term of endearment is *darling*. I don't think you'll find a synonym that has the same derivation or underlying meaning of "can't get enough of you" or "can't take my eyes off you", despite both expressions being idiomatic.

Comment: It just means *sweetheart* or *love*. These do not have the original meaning of the Russian word, but the Russian word doesn't have the original meaning of the Russian word, either. Do not translate words literally morpheme-for-morpheme. That's called the etymological fallacy. Try translating the word "woman" literally. Or "October". See where that gets you. I am a native speaker of Russian, I have studied translation at university level, and I am closing this question as off-topic for the main site. You are welcome to take it to our chat instead, where translators hang around 24/7. Cheers.

Comment: I personally liked the question, but I feel it would have done better if it had a sample sentence justifying why preserving both commonplace and literal meanings were needed, e.g.  some kind of a pun or a proverb. Not sure such word exists in English though. Anyway, for the sake of completeness, another translation option might be "**precious**", though it does not fit your requirements either.

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be appropriate to use 
***magnetic***  here.

There's a strong metaphorical transfer of the original meaning (someone's appearance may be compared with a magnet).

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magnetic):

***MAGNETIC***

: possessing an extraordinary power or ability to attract

// a magnetic
personality